# Blazor Web App (.net 8) - switch user authentication to use SQLite instead of SQL Server

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I am trying to see if switching from using SQL Server to SQLite for the built in user authorization / authentication in the demo Blazor web app (on .NET 8).

I used the following as a base

https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-i-implement-authentication-using-sqlite-in-blazor

I changed the `appsettings.json` file

```
"DefaultConnection": "c:\\MyDir\\MyUsers.db"
```

I changed the `builder.Services` reference in `Program.cs`:

```
// builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>                options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services
       .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connectionString));
```

I uninstalled `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`.

I now get x3 errors in the `ApplicationDbContextModelSnapshot.cs` file (all same error)

> Error CS0103
> The name 'SqlServerModelBuilderExtensions' does not exist in the current context  MyAppName

I am not sure how to go about modifying this to eliminate the error. The Syncfusion example was from an earlier version of .NET - so it does not apply directly.x 3

Answer (score 4):

Remove the migration(s) and the snapshot. Just delete all files in the Migrations folder.

Then generate a new initial migration.
In the Package Manager Console, type `add-migration Initial`.

Alternatively you can use `dotnet new` on the command line to generate a new project. You can choose which db is used, SQLite is the default.

```
dotnet new blazor --auth Individual
```

add `--use-local-db` for ms-sql and nothing for SQLite

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - just to make sure as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers?tabs=dotnet-core-cli  would I run the following `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context SqliteBlogContext --output-dir Migrations/SqliteMigrations`

Comment: Yes, or the shorter Pkg Mgr Console command (`add-migration Initial`, if all is default).

Answer (score 0):

@H H

As per H H - his suggestion worked

I deleted all the files in the `Migrations` folder
I the ran

```
add-migration Initial
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

I then did an

```
Update-Database
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
   at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Storage.Internal.SqliteDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0.
```

I then changed the connection string in `appsettings.json` from

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "c:\\MyDir\\MyDb.db"
  },
```

to

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source = c:\\MyDir\\MyDb.db"
  },
```

With that - the application runs, SQLite Studio shows all the database tables created, and users are added to the tables, and the application authenticates well

Thanks for the help.